# Search a table for doc_names and compare with Codes Table?

Tags: sql

Basically I am trying to look at the file_place table and find all doc names with a specific id that are in the codes_document_names table.

```
SELECT DOC_NAME 
FROM FILE_PLACE 
WHERE  LINKED_ID = 140145 
 and DOC_NAME like (select distinct document_name from codes_document_names)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `LIKE`, you can use `IN`:

```
SELECT DOC_NAME 
FROM FILE_PLACE 
WHERE  LINKED_ID = 140145 
 and DOC_NAME IN (select document_name 
                  from codes_document_names)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91053/3)

You should also be able to use a `JOIN` instead of the `IN`:

```
select DOC_NAME
from FILE_PLACE f
inner join codes_document_names d
  on f.DOC_NAME = d.document_name
where LINKED_ID = 140145
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91053/8)

Answer (score 1):

@Bluefeet slightly improving your answer,

```
SELECT DOC_NAME 
FROM FILE_PLACE 
WHERE  LINKED_ID = 140145 
 and lower(DOC_NAME) IN (select distinct 
     lower(document_name) from codes_document_names)
```